# Can I accelerate the prep time for small tapioca pearls?

Tags: pudding

I've got a package of Reese small pearl tapioca in front of me, ready to make tapioca pudding, but I forgot to factor in the recommended overnight soak. Is it possible to accelerate the process by soaking in warm or boiling water or by substituting a longer cooking time?

Comment: Typically for starches & hydrocoloids, you need to hydrate them fully before heating, or the outside will gelatinize preventing the middle from hydrating.  Sometimes things are sold 'pre-gelatinized' (eg, Wondra flour, 'instant' tapioca) that don't require the cold soak first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works without presoaking. You have to cook them for quite a long time until they become quickly translucent, the small ones will need about 30 minutes at a moderate boil. It is not optimal, as the outside will become mushier in this long cooking time, but there are people who don't mind the difference.